# Error while importing HoloToolkit-Unity-2017.4.2.0 on Unity 2018.1.6f1 Personal

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, visual-studio-2017, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

While importing HoloToolkit-Unity-2017.4.2.0 on Unity (Version 2018.1.6f1 (57cc34175ccf) Personal
Branch: 2018.1/release)
PS: This unity installed by Visual studio itself.

To Reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1.Open Unity and Go to Assets -> Import Packages

2. Click on Custom Packages... and select HoloToolkit-Unity-2017.4.2.0.unitypackage
3. and after that click on import.
4. After import done , following error and warning occurs.
5. Also clicking on Apply Mixed Reality Project Settings will not update anything.

   Error is

   **System.Exception: Package directory not found: "C:\Users\xyz.nuget\packages\Microsoft.CSharp\4.0.1".
       at UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.NuGetPackageResolver.Resolve () [0x000dd] in <3f368bacb6c34f4db5fe7e90570f303a>:0**

   Warning are

   - Model 'Cursor_cross_root' contains animation clip 'Cursor_Cross_Hold_GestureFOV_root' which has length of 0 frames (start=132, end=132). It will result in empty animation.
   - Model 'Cursor_cross_root' contains animation clip 'Cursor_Cross_GestureFOV_off_root' which has length of 0 frames (start=132, end=132). It will result in empty animation
   - Model 'Cursor_cross_root' contains animation clip 'Cursor' which has length of 0 frames (start=1, end=1). It will result in empty animation.
   - Model 'CursorRing' contains animation clip 'Cursor' which has length of 0 frames (start=5, end=5). It will result in empty animation.

Before importing HTK

[image]

Error occurred after import

[image]
Please help!

Comment: I have this all time after rebuilding external DLLs when Unity (2018.2.5) reimports them. It's a bit annoying but you can clear and ignore this. It will show up only after reimporting MRT or other DLLs